# VB.NET: Avoiding redundancies

Tags: vb.net, class, module

Each of my VB.NET projects needs a certain set of custom modules. 
For example:

modLog
modGUID
modControls
modRegistry

In SOME of these modules I have a few references to other modules.

For example the sub modLog.WriteLog goes like this:

```
Public Sub WriteLog(Byval uText As String)

 If globalclassOEM.IsOEMVersion Then
     sPath = (some custom path)
 Else
     sPath = (some default path)
 End  if

 'Write log text to file

End Sub
```

This is really stupid because sometimes I have to add really many modules and classes to a tiny projects just to solve some dependencies as the above and to be able to use a few modules that I really need.

Is there any best tactics in VB.NET to avoid such situations?

Comment: Yes, don't hardlink the classes, modules and dlls if they work independently.

Comment: Don't use global static variables (variables at module level), neverever. Consider using techniques like dependency injection. Use iterfaces to decouple dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to avoid such problems, would be to avoid that problem ;) Means: Libraries should do exactly what they are meant to do and not do some "extra work" in the backgorund. In your example: Why does the WriteLog function need to determine the path and why doesnt the caller define it and pass it to the logging function/class?

IF you still want or need to have the functions in that way, you might circumvent the problem by defining interfaces and then put ALL your interfaces into a single library, but NOT the classes that implement them. That would still require to load the file with the interface definitions, but of course you don't need to load any class that implements it.

You might also use some kind of plugin system and when your logging class (in this example) is  created, it might try to dynamically load the required assemblies. If they do not exit, the class will without them, otherwise it can use them as pretended. Doesnt make programmers life easier, though (imho).

The "best" way (imho again) would be the first suggestion. Dont have "low level" libraries referencing other libraries. Everything else most likely would be considered to be a design flaw and not a "solution".

Answer (score 1):

I have not covered a whole heap of referencing in VB.net, however, would it be possible for you to create a .dll with all the base modules. This would mean you could reference this .dll saving you time. For the extenuating circumstances where you have references to other modules you could just manually write that module.

Answer (score 1):

As others have alluded to, you never want to directly include the same code file in multiple projects.  That is almost never a good idea and it always leads to messy code.  If you have common code that you want to share between two different projects, then you need to create a third project (a class library) which will contain the common code, and then the other two projects will just reference to the class library.  It's best if you can have all three projects in the same solution and then you can use project references.  However, if you can't do that, you can still have a direct file reference to the DLL that is output by that class library project.

Secondly, if you really want to avoid spaghetti code, you should seriously look into dependency-injection (DI).  The reason I, and others have suggested this, is because, even if you move the common code into class libraries so that it can be shared by multiple projects, you'll still have the problem that your class libraries act as "black-boxes" that magically figure out everything for you and act appropriately in every situation.  On the face of it, that sounds like a good thing for which a developer should strive, but in reality, that leads to bad code in the long run.

For instance, what happens when you want to use the same logging class library in 100 different projects and they all need to do logging in slightly different ways.  Now, your class library has to magically detect all of those different situations and handle them all.  For instance, some projects may need to save the log to a different file name.  Some may need to store the log to the Windows event log or a database.  Some may need to automatically email a notification when an error is logged.  Etc.  As you can imagine, as the projects increase and the requirements grow, the logging class library will need to get more and more complex and confusing which will inevitably lead to more bugs.

DI, on the other hand, solves all these issues, and if you adhere to the methodology, it will essentially force you to write reusable code.  In simple terms, it just means that all the dependencies of a class should be injected (passed by parameter) into it.  In other words, if the Logger class needs an event log, or a database connection, it should not create or reach out and find those things itself.  Instead, it should simply require that those dependencies be passed into it (often in the constructor).  Your example using DI might look something like this:

```
Public Interface ILogFilePathFinder
    Function GetPath() As String
End Interface

Public Class LogFilePathFinder
    Implements ILogFilePathFinder

    Public Sub New(isOemVersion As Boolean)
        _isOemVersion = isOemVersion
    End Sub

    Private _isOemVersion As Boolean

    Function GetPath() As String Implements ILogFilePathFinder.GetPath
        If _isOemVersion Then
            Return "C:\TestOem.log"
        Else
            Return "C:\Test.log"
        End If
    End Function
End Class

Public Interface ILogger
    Sub WriteLog(ByVal text As String)
End Interface

Public Class FileLogger
    Implements ILogger

    Public Sub New(pathFinder As ILogFilePathFinder)
        _pathFinder = pathFinder
    End Sub

    _pathFinder As ILogFilePathFinder

    Public Sub WriteLog(text As String) Implements ILogger.WriteLog
        Dim path As String = _pathFinder.GetPath()
        ' Write text to file ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, it requires a little bit of extra work, but when you design your code like this, you'll never regret it.  You'll notice that the logger class requests a path finder as a dependency.  The path finder, in turn, requests an OEM setting as a dependency.  So, to use it, you would need to do something like this:

```
Dim pathFinder As ILogFilePathFinder = New FileLogPathFinder(_OemSettings.IsOemVersion)  ' Note, don't use a global to store the settings, always ask for them to be injected
Dim logger As ILogger = New FileLogger(pathFinder)
logger.WriteLog("test")
```

Now, you can easily reuse all of this code in any situation.  For instance, if you have different projects that need to use a different log file path, they can still use the common `FileLogger` class, they just need to each implement their own version of `ILogFilePathFinder` and then inject that custom path finder into the common `FileLogger`.  Hopefully you see how doing it this way can be very useful and flexible.